# correct way to add file path in ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

A file which is accessed by Ajax if has to include other file (.css, .js, .php etc) we have to define its full path as `../../user/myfile.php`, there might be many parent directories so adding `../../../../` makes confusing.
Is there anyway so that it should start entering from the Root like `/root/..../user/myfile.php`

**Example**

---

i am accessing a file using ajax as `$("#box").load("/root/sub1/sub2/file.php");`

**file.php**
in this file i am including other file as `include("../../otherfile.php");`

**Note**
i tried `include("/root/sub1/otherfile.php");` which not works and puts error `file not found`

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. On one of my machines, `c:\xampp\htdocs` maps to `localhost` If I include a path in an html file that is `/`, then it will point to the root of the html folder. In my case, it's the folder I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/` at the beginning of the path will start from the root. So if your file is at

```
example.com/styles/global.css
```

and you're currently in

```
example.com/very/long/path/that/you/dont/want/to/use/relative/paths/to.php
```

You can ajax to

```
/styles/global.css
```

Easy enough, right? Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: i tried it, it only works if we simply include any file, but here i am accessing a file using `$("#box").load('/root/../file.php');` and in `file.php` i have to include other file as `include("/root/../otherfile.php");` which gives error `file not found` but if i use `../../otherfile.php` it works